# Problem with in Angular (only in prod mode)

Tags: angular, typescript, router

If I inform in the browser https://beeidea.com.br/, it is redirected without problems to https://beeidea.com.br/home. However, if I type https://beeidea.com.br/home in the address bar, it shows the code 404

Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53856360/how-does-angular-routing-take-precedence-over-file-paths-on-a-static-site/53856419#53856419 This question is basically the same

Comment: thanks @bryan60. this topic solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return index.html file on server.
something like:

```
this.expressApp.get("/*", function (req, res, next) {
            return res.sendFile(clientFolder + '/index.html');
 })
```